# how to view certificate detail that contains more than one certificates

Tags: openssl, ssl

In ubuntu 16.04 OS there is `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` which has a lot of:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

how can I view what certificates are in the file as individual certificate, one by one?

I have tried:

```
openssl x509 -noout  -issuer -subject -dates -in ca-certificates.crt
```

but it looks as there is only one cert in it:

```
issuer= /CN=ACCVRAIZ1/OU=PKIACCV/O=ACCV/C=ES
subject= /CN=ACCVRAIZ1/OU=PKIACCV/O=ACCV/C=ES
notBefore=May  5 09:37:37 2011 GMT
notAfter=Dec 31 09:37:37 2030 GMT
```

Shouldnt there be more? How can I see all of them?

Comment: [Please see this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle) from another SE site.

Comment: So `ca-certificates.crt` is what is called a `bundle`?

Comment: Yeah "bundle" is just a generic term for when you have multiple certs in the same file.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not know that. Thank you